# How to add post format to theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

For classipress theme. I can register post_formats the normal way in functions (works - I can select "link" type in the editor), but I can't figure out how to get it to actually use a template file for link posts.

I have used the `get_template_part('content', get_post_format())`; in the past successfully,

but I can't figure how to inject that into the single.php's code for this theme:

Single.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package ClassiPress\Templates
 * @author  AppThemes
 * @since   ClassiPress 1.0
 */
?>


<div class="content">

    <div class="content_botbg">

        <div class="content_res">

            <div id="breadcrumb"><?php cp_breadcrumb(); ?></div>

            <div class="content_left">

                <?php appthemes_before_blog_loop(); ?>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


                        <?php appthemes_before_blog_post(); ?>

                        <?php appthemes_stats_update( $post->ID ); //records the page hit ?>

                        <div class="shadowblock_out">

                            <div class="shadowblock">

                                <div class="post">




                                    <?php appthemes_before_blog_post_title(); ?>




                                    <h1 class="single blog"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                                    <?php appthemes_after_blog_post_title(); ?>
<div style="margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">
<?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(); } ?>
</div>

                                    <?php appthemes_before_blog_post_content(); ?>

                                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>

                                        <div id="main-pic">
                                            <?php cp_get_blog_image_url(); ?>
                                        </div>

                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php the_content(); ?>




                                    <div class="dotted"></div>
                                    <div class="pad5"></div>

                                    <?php appthemes_after_blog_post_content(); ?>



                                </div><!-- .post -->

                            </div><!-- .shadowblock -->

                        </div><!-- .shadowblock_out -->

                        <?php appthemes_after_blog_post(); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php appthemes_after_blog_endwhile(); ?>

                <?php else: ?>

                    <?php appthemes_blog_loop_else(); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="clr"></div>

                <?php appthemes_after_blog_loop(); ?>

                <div class="clr"></div>

                <?php comments_template(); ?>


            </div><!-- .content_left -->

            <?php get_sidebar( 'blog' ); ?>

            <div class="clr"></div>

        </div><!-- .content_res -->

    </div><!-- .content_botbg -->

</div><!-- .content -->
```

Content.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Post loop content template.
 *
 * @package ClassiPress\Templates
 * @author  AppThemes
 * @since   ClassiPress 3.4
 */
?>

<div <?php post_class( 'shadowblock_out' ); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

    <div class="shadowblock">

        <?php appthemes_before_blog_post_title(); ?>

        <h3 class="loop"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <?php appthemes_after_blog_post_title(); ?>

        <?php appthemes_before_blog_post_content(); ?>

        <div class="entry-content">

            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) the_post_thumbnail( 'blog-thumbnail' ); ?>

            <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading ...', APP_TD ) ); ?>

        </div>

        <?php appthemes_after_blog_post_content(); ?>

    </div><!-- #shadowblock -->

</div><!-- #shadowblock_out -->
```

Tried a lot of things, unsuccessful in doing anything but breaking the page.

Thanks

Comment: What is your goal, what your'e trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Just trying to be able to use a different post format for some of my single posts.

Comment: Please post your whole single.php file.

Comment: Updated to include entire single.php

Comment: @Jay what about doing this with https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

Comment: Can't use those because they're for 'pages', not for posts, unfortunately.

Comment: @jay have you tried this plugin? https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-post-template/

Comment: I have, but more plugins is not what I'm craving

Comment: Also, that plugin doesn't work with this theme, it seems. Tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Post formats](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) are used to customize the presentation of post items. If you check out some theme that supports post formats (For example [Twenty Fifteen](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/)), you will see that the [single.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/single.php) file is not used to output the contents of the post - which is delegated to content-*.php files. (For example, the `the_content()` function, which outputs a post's content is not in `single.php`, but in `content.php` (and `content-link.php` and others).

Your `single.php` does not seem to be built this way, so it does not support post formats, but it can be refactored easily, just split it into two files (in single.php you should keep the "frame" code that is common for every post format, then move the rest into a new content.php file, which will be used as the default format):

**single.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package ClassiPress\Templates
 * @author  AppThemes
 * @since   ClassiPress 1.0
 */
?>


<div class="content">

    <div class="content_botbg">

        <div class="content_res">

            <div id="breadcrumb"><?php cp_breadcrumb(); ?></div>

            <div class="content_left">

                <?php appthemes_before_blog_loop(); ?>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


                        <?php appthemes_before_blog_post(); ?>

                        <?php appthemes_stats_update( $post->ID ); //records the page hit ?>

                        <?php
                            // Note the below line which loads the desired content*.php
                            get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); 
                        ?>

                        <?php appthemes_after_blog_post(); ?>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <?php appthemes_after_blog_endwhile(); ?>

                <?php else: ?>

                    <?php appthemes_blog_loop_else(); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="clr"></div>

                <?php appthemes_after_blog_loop(); ?>

                <div class="clr"></div>

                <?php comments_template(); ?>


            </div><!-- .content_left -->

            <?php get_sidebar( 'blog' ); ?>

            <div class="clr"></div>

        </div><!-- .content_res -->

    </div><!-- .content_botbg -->

</div><!-- .content -->
```

**content.php**

```
                        <div class="shadowblock_out">

                            <div class="shadowblock">

                                <div class="post">




                                    <?php appthemes_before_blog_post_title(); ?>




                                    <h1 class="single blog"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                                    <?php appthemes_after_blog_post_title(); ?>
<div style="margin-top:10px; text-align:center;">
<?php if ( function_exists( 'ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT' ) ) { ADDTOANY_SHARE_SAVE_KIT(); } ?>
</div>

                                    <?php appthemes_before_blog_post_content(); ?>

                                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?>

                                        <div id="main-pic">
                                            <?php cp_get_blog_image_url(); ?>
                                        </div>

                                    <?php endif; ?>

                                    <?php the_content(); ?>




                                    <div class="dotted"></div>
                                    <div class="pad5"></div>

                                    <?php appthemes_after_blog_post_content(); ?>



                                </div><!-- .post -->

                            </div><!-- .shadowblock -->

                        </div><!-- .shadowblock_out -->
```

Now, for additional post formats, for example `gallery`, you will have to create a file named `content-gallery.php` and implement it. You can derive it from the default `content.php`, but you decide how it should look like.

Comment: In this theme, there actually already is a content.php file. I'm putting it up at the top of this page. Since there is one though, I guess making a new content.php in the way you described can't be done (or maybe I'm wrong?)  Is there a way still?

Comment: If you compare the existing content.php wit the one I suggested, you will notice that they are actually almost the same. I'm thinking the extra code was added by you in single.php. I would make a backup of the current content.php and replace it with the version I provided, then test it. You could search in which template files within the theme there is a reference to the content template (by searching for `'content'` in your theme files) and test those templates whether they still work ok after the change.

Comment: Yes, you were absolutely right with these two files (although the code was actually part of the theme itself). After adding this and a content-link file, everything works. Thanks again. Do you you have a thing where I can buy you a beer?